# MS Windows socket example not working for me

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I'm trying to run the Windows sockets example outlined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Running the server code in VS debugger, it hangs on the accept() call here:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections.
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL); // *** blocks here ***
    printf("accept completed!");

    return 0;
}
```

I originally expected this to complete immediately and successfully (but fbidwell explained why this wouldn't be the case).

Since I'm pretty sure about a million people have run this successfully, I'm guessing it's not the code, so it's something in my environment. I'm running Windows 7, VS Community 2015. Any suggestions on what settings I should check to get this seemingly simple example to work?

EDIT: As Remy Lebeau pointed out in his comment, the WSAECONREFUSED was a red herring for me. fbidwell's explanation answers my question.

I'm building for .NET 4.5.2 also, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that the code will hang once it reaches the accept() call,  this is the point where the server is waiting for a client connection in order to continue on.  You should compile the example client from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx) and run it after the server is up and running.  Once the client hits the connect() call you should see the accept return.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was working, but this time I stepped through the client and got a WSAECONNREFUSED error on the connect().

Comment: `WSAECONNREFUSED` means the connection was actively refused. That can happen if either 1) the client tries to connect to a server IP:Port that is not listening for clients at all. The IP was reached, but the Port is not open. 2) the IP is reached and the Port is open, but the port's backlog of pending clients is full. Try again later after the server has had a chance to accept some clients from its backlog. 3) a firewall is blocking the connection. Unfortunately, there is no way for the client it know which of these conditions is causing `WSAECONNREFUSED`, all it can do is try again later.